# What is wrong with this function to delete node from a BST?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I simply want to delete a node from the BST and this gives me an error that new is undefined. 
The ADT is like this:

```
typedef struct BSTNode *BSTree;
struct BSTNode {
    int value;
    BSTree left;
    BSTree right;
};

 BSTree Delete(BSTree t, int item) {
        if (item < t->value) {
            t->left = Delete(t->left, item);
        } else if (item > t->value) {
            t->right = Delete(t->right, item);
        } else {
            // deleting item
            if (t->left == NULL && t->right == NULL) {
                BSTree new = NULL;
            } else if (t->left == NULL) {
                BSTree new = t->right;
            } else if (t->right == NULL) {
                BSTree new = t->left;
           // } else {
                //BSTree new = joinTrees(t->left, t->right);
            }

            free(t);
            t = new;
        }
```

Comment: `new` might be a reserved keyword in C too, try using another variable name. Also it's declared in the inner scope, declare it where `// deleting item` comment is.

Comment: I do not recommend the typedef of `BSTree`.  It obscures the fact that it's a pointer. And everyone generally recognizes that a "tree" is the root node pointer itself.  This is just an opinion, not a fact.

Comment: Your `Delete` function should check for `t == NULL` first. If it is, just return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are declaring multiple variables that only exist within each containing conditional block. Declare the variable at the top of the function or top of the `else` block. Then set that same variable in each conditional block of code.

```
BSTree Delete(BSTree t, int item) {
    BSTree new_item;
    if (item < t->value) {
        t->left = Delete(t->left, item);
    } else if (item > t->value) {
        t->right = Delete(t->right, item);
    } else {
        // deleting item
        if (t->left == NULL && t->right == NULL) {
            new_item = NULL;
        } else if (t->left == NULL) {
            new_item = t->right;
        } else if (t->right == NULL) {
            new_item = t->left;
       // } else {
            //BSTree new = joinTrees(t->left, t->right);
        }

        free(t);
        t = new_item;
    }
```